# How to know which block I am mining solo in bitcoin core wallet?

Tags: solo-mining

[image]**How to know which block I am mining solo in bitcoin core wallet? How do I know which block I'm in? And how to know how many blocks are left for me to mine 1 whole block by myself?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last question seems to imply that you think that there is some guarantee that after enough blocks you will mine a block. This is not the case. You could mine a block right this moment, although it is extremely unlikely. As the total hasrate of the network increases the probability of you mining a block is getting smaller and smaller, to the point that it is not economical to even try; you'll be paying more in energy bills to have your PC running than the block rewards will yield you.

Answer (score 0):

> **How to know which block I am mining solo in bitcoin core wallet?**

https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getmininginfo.html says

> "blocks" : n,                (numeric) The current block

Your screenshot shows

> "blocks" : 737143

That gives you the information you seek.

---

> **How do I know which block I'm in?**

I don't know what you mean by that.

You aren't ever *in* a block, but you are only ever mining the next possible block. The one whose block height is 1 more than the last block mined.

---

> **how to know how many blocks are left for me to mine 1 whole block by myself?**

You can only mine the next block. One that is a descendent block of the last mined block. (by which I mean a block that contains a reference to the block-ID of the block most recently mined by the Bitcoin network).

Beyond that are an almost infinite number of blocks to be mined.

---

Note that mining blocks in mainnet is a hopeless task unless you are using recent ASICs.